# jqGrid - Is there any "grid edit mode"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm new with the jqGrid and I want to know if there is any way I can set the whole grid in edit mode.

I just have one editable column. It is basically a checkbox list. My first approach was this code when the user enters in edit mode:

```
var ids = $("#tblPermisos").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    $('#tblPermisos').editRow(ids[i], false);
```

This seem to work great, but when the users changes the page all rows in edit mode are canceled (or saved, don't know). I'd prefer to avoid handling the events to keep edit mode for all rows. So, back to my question, is there any "grid edit mode" or other simpler way than handling events?

Comment: What does it mean to "set the whole grid in edit mode"?

Comment: Set all grids in edit mode and keep them like that until some method call to say the opposite.

Comment: I did a little online research, and I did not find any "toggle" to keep a grid in edit mode continuously. Places I looked are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170260/jqgrid-all-rows-in-inline-edit-mode-by-default and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow

Comment: Ok :( I hoped there was something I was missing. Thanks. Put this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little online research, and I did not find any "toggle" to keep a grid in edit mode continuously. Places I looked are [jqGrid: All rows in "inline edit mode" by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170260/jqgrid-all-rows-in-inline-edit-mode-by-default) and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow