# Jquery JQgrid, show input field

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datatables, jqgrid-php

I have a JQGrid with an input field, which works fine, but I would like to have the field always shown, now the user has to click in the field to see the input text field appear.

```
      colModel:[ {name:'Image', index:'Image', width:10, formatter: imageFormatter, align: 'center', sortable:false},                     
                 {name:'ItemId', index:'ItemId', width:15, align: 'center'}, 
                 {name:'ItemName', index:'ItemName'},                     
                 {name:'UnitId', index:'UnitId', width:10, align: 'center'},
                 {name:'MultipleQty', index:'MultipleQty', width:10, align: 'right'},
                 {name:'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', align:'center',editable:true,editrules:{number:true}, edittype:'text', width:14,editoptions:{size:5,maxlength:5}},
                 {name:'Basket', index:'Basket', width:7, formatter: basketFormatter, align: 'center', sortable:false}                  
               ],
```

It's the quantity field, which option can I use to have the field always shown ?
Where can I find the documentation surrounding all possible options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I finally found the solution :

[jqGrid: All rows in "inline edit mode" by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170260/jqgrid-all-rows-in-inline-edit-mode-by-default)

I added this :

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        $this.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
    }
}
```